# Get the char from scanf("%d")

Tags: c, scanf

When using `scanf("%d", &input)` if the user inputs `a` is there any way to get the inputted char?

Comment: Call `getchar` if `scanf` returns 0?

Comment: Just assign the `input` to a `char` variable.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not.

What you can do is using a combo of `fgets` and `sscanf`

```
int input;
char buffer[100]; // Or whatever size you want
if(! fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
if(sscanf(buffer, "%d", &input) != 1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

The code will exit the program upon failure, but if there is no failure and that the input is not bigger than buffer, then you will have the complete input in buffer.